# Erro ao retornar dados do array JS

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Preciso atribuir os atributos ao objeto de forma relativa, sem saber quantos parâmetros irão vir, dessa forma não está retornando resultados, existe outro método?

```
    var menu = document.getElementById("funcaoMenu").value;

    res = menu.split(","); //divide os resultados pela "," e cria um array


    oi = new Object(); // instância um novo objeto


    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        oi.i = res[i]; // recebe os dados do array e alterna a chave
    };
```

os dados que recebo são parâmetros em string, exemplo: "menu","rodapé","ola".

e preciso executar esses dados em um parâmetro em php para usar a função e func_num_args e func_get_args.

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo dos dados que recebes e do formato que queres obter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que você deva fazer a atribuição assim:

```
oi[i] = res[i];
```